# Magento Join Product Collection to Custom Table on Custom Attribute

Tags: magento

In Magento, how can a standard product collection be joined to a custom table on a custom attribute.

So for example, I have a custom product attribute warehouse_id and a custom table warehouse and now want a collection with product name, warehouse name.

Code example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinAttribute('warehouse_id', 'warehouse/warehouse', 'warehouse_id', null, 'inner');
var_dump($collection);
```

However, this does not work because warehouse is a custom table/collection and is not in the 
eav_entity_type table.

Turning the problem around thought this might work:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('warehouse/warehouse')->getCollection()->joinAttribute( etc.
```

However, joinAttribute is not a method on my custom collection.

Have read every example, every post, wiki example etc. and cannot grasp how to do this.  A specific code example would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think joinAttribute could possibly work if some of the parameters were changed. I'm a little more familiar with [join and joinLeft](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento) which are more like working directly with mysql queries.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(array('warehouse_id'=>'warehouse'),'e.warehouse_id = warehouse_id.warehouse_id', array('name'));
var_dump($collection);
```

This assumes that the name of your custom table is `warehouse`and that the field in your custom table that corresponds to the custom `warehouse_id` attribute is also called `warehouse_id`. This also assumes that the field for the name of the warehouse in your custom table is `name`. You might have to do something like this instead of naming the table directly:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(array('warehouse_id'=>$this->getTable('warehouse/warehouse')),'e.warehouse_id = warehouse_id.warehouse_id', array('name'));
var_dump($collection);
```

If neither work, replace the var_dump line with the line:

```
echo $this->escapeHtml($collection->getSelect());
```

And post the resulting sql query here.